# PHP & Symfony 3: Email does not send after pressing submit on form but sends successfully using 'php bin\console swiftmailer:email:send'

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, symfony-3.4

Exactly what the title implies. I am attempting to send an email after a user submits a form.  It may or may not be relevant, but I am using the ekino wordpress/symfony bundle found [here](https://github.com/ekino/EkinoWordpressBundle).  I believe I have narrowed it down to the following line:

```
$form->handleRequest($request);
```

If I have this in the code under the createFormBuilder() piece and I click the submit button, I get the following error

```
Warning: "continue" targeting switch is equivalent to "break". Did you mean to use "continue 2"?
```

If I comment that piece out, the form appears to submit but no email ever arrives.  Below is the entire function.  Thanks for any advice in advance.

```
public function joinTeamPageAction(Request $request){

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->add('from', EmailType::class)
        ->add('message', TextareaType::class)
        ->add('send',SubmitType::class)
        ->getForm()
    ;

    $form->handleRequest($request);


    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()){
        $data = $form->getData();

        $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
            ->setSubject('Join Our Team Request')
            ->setFrom($data['from'])
            ->setTo('emailme@example.com')
            ->setBody(
                $data['message'],'text/plain'
            )
        ;

        $this->get('mailer')->send($message);
    }

    return $this->render('/join_team/join_team.html.twig', array("title" => "Join Team","join_team_form" => $form->createView()));
}
```

Comment: This warning came about in PHP 7.3, and one of your dependencies was written for an older version. Bringing your libs up-to-date with `composer update` will likely fix this issue, but may introduce other problems.

Comment: @AlexHowansky Success!!!